# Select items that doesn't have a specific value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, outer-join

I am trying to select items that doesn't have a specific value in another table, I was able to achieve the result that I wanted by using a subquery, however it's very slow so I am wondering if I could do it differently...

```
SELECT
    content.*,
    (SELECT views
     FROM content_views
     WHERE content_views.content = content.record_num
    ) as views
FROM content
RIGHT JOIN watch_log ON content.record_num = watch_log.content
WHERE content.enabled = 1
    AND 24 NOT IN
        (SELECT niche
         FROM content_niches
         WHERE content_niches.content = content.record_num
        )
ORDER BY content.encoded_date
DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

I tried using a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but couldn't get the same result...

```
SELECT
    content.*,
    (SELECT content_views.views
     FROM content_views
     WHERE content_views.content = content.record_num
    ) as views
FROM content
RIGHT JOIN watch_log ON content.record_num = watch_log.content
LEFT OUTER JOIN content_niches ON content.record_num = content_niches.content AND content_niches.niche = 24
WHERE content.enabled = 1
ORDER BY content.encoded_date
DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

Comment: Why that RIGHT JOIN?!?

Comment: Esspecially if there is a `WHERE content.enabled = 1` condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing left and right outer joins is just confusing.  In fact, `right join` isn't really needed.  It can usually be replaced by `left join`.  In your case, it can be replaced by inner join, because the `where` clause turns it into an inner join.  So, how about:

```
SELECT c.*,
       (SELECT views
        FROM content_views cv
        WHERE cv.content =  c.record_num
       ) as views
FROM content c JOIN
     watch_log wl
     ON c.record_num = wl.content
WHERE c.enabled = 1 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM content_niches cn
                  WHERE cn.content = c.record_num AND
                        cn.niche = 24
                 )
ORDER BY c.encoded_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 6;
```

For performance you want indexes:  `content(enabled, encoded_date, record_num)`, `content_views(content, views)`, and `content_niches(content, niche)`.

Notes:

- Don't mix different types of outer joins, unless you really, really understand what they are doing.
- Use table aliases that abbreviations of the table names.  This makes queries easier to write and to read.
- Whatever your preference for formatting, don't start a line in a query with `DESC` (or `ASC`); this is a modifier on `ORDER BY`.
- `NOT EXISTS` is better than `NOT IN`.  The former handles `NULL` values the way you would expect.  The latter returns nothing if there are `NULL` values.

Comment: So I did as you indicated, all the columns were already indexed as BTREE. But how come you are not indicated the JOIN direction ?

Comment: @Dacramash . . .  I'm not sure what you mean.  No "direction" is needed for the join because it is an `inner join`.